# Can an infection with toxoplasma gondii be cured with the current medical state of the art?

Tags: mental-health, infection, treatment, immune-system, parasites

According to the [CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/parasites/toxoplasmosis/epi.html), toxoplasma gondii is purported to be present in approximately 22.5% of those in the US above the age of 12, and is present in some populations worldwide at an incidence rate of over 90%. It has been linked to mental health problems in humans, with [one study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3515034/) for example showing strong potential for the parasite to cause schizophrenia, and mentioning abundant evidence of the parasite causing brain changes in other hosts.

Doing my due diligence, I found plenty of information from the CDC, Mayo Clinic and so on indicating that the infection is generally asymptomatic, which is essentially proxy terminology for "doesn't cause any symptoms we're looking for," and so is generally not treated. If it is treated, however, no resource I could find indicates whether treatment actually eliminates the parasite, or simply holds it at bay.

**Does modern medicine allow us to "cure" toxoplasma gondii infection, or will an infected individual continue to carry the parasite for life?**